# Styling the new Windows 8.1 searchbox to use the glyph only

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

Does anyone have an example on how to style the new SearchBox (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn252771) to show a glyph only? Some of the Windows 8.1 store apps show the searchbox with the search glyph only and when you press the search glyph the textbox appears.

I haven't been able to find a sample app showing this.

Comment: It's gotta be a custom styling on it. I can't seem to find where they have posted the default style templates for the SearchBox (it's likely they have not yet done so, as the class definition itself is still 'preliminary'). I don't yet have Windows 8.1 installed, so I'm also unable to get the default style. If you wouldn't mind trying to find it, I would be willing to take a look. I'm not 100% sure if this will work, but if you right click the SearchBox in the designer and go down to "Edit Templates", you may be able to find the default style and post it here.

Comment: Hi,This is the style: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwaBDWc05M-UeGpuakVRbDBUTEk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you find a good solution to this?

Comment: @SimonMunro Check my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

As Vlad's Answer metioned You need to create a style.

> Add a SearchBox to your page, then right-click on it in the designer and select Edit template.

Then inside the style from blend, You need to modify normal, Focused state and FocusedDropDown state to auto show/hide on focus changing.

Here are a proposed steps using blend that will work with you,

The final code is here in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/arashadm/961844c97307c2d74658)

1- Add SearchBox

```
<SearchBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" Margin="0,15,0,0"/>
```

Add also empty button to capture the initial focus on search Box, Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20552764/2086772).

```
<Button Width="0" Height="0"/>
```

2- Right Click on SearchBox to edit template

[image: Template]

3- Inside the template, change width of SearchBoxGrid to 32 only to show the glyph and set horizontal alignment to Right.

[image]

4- Select states tab in blend then select focused state.

[image]

5- Set Width of SearchBoxGrid grid to auto again and set horizontal alignment to stretch.

[image]

or add those lines manually in focused state

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="SearchBoxGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <x:Double>NaN</x:Double>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment)" Storyboard.TargetName="SearchBoxGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <HorizontalAlignment>Stretch</HorizontalAlignment>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

6- Do the same 4 & 5 steps in focused drop down state.

Answer (score 1):

Add a SearchBox to your page, then right-click on it in the designer and select Edit template. Create a copy and style it as you want.